# Discord.js Displaying sqlite rows in message?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, discord.js

I am fairly new to discord.js, and am having trouble displaying/sorting the data from an sqlite database in a message. I am currently updating each users row upon them sending a message in the server, which is working fine. However, I would like a 'leaderboard' of sorts, using the data that is contained in the database.

Here is a refined version of what I am trying:

```
var Discord = require('discord.js');
var bot = new Discord.Client();
var moment = require('moment');
var Roll = require('roll'),
const sql = require("sqlite");
sql.open("userData.sqlite");

bot.on('message', message => {

var prefix = config.prefix;
var sender = message.author;
var msg = message.content.toUpperCase();

sql.get(`SELECT * FROM userData WHERE userId ="${message.author.id}"`).then(row => {
        if (!row) {
            sql.run("INSERT INTO userData (userId, username, level, money, time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [message.author.id, sender.username, 0, 0, 0]);
        }
    }).catch(() => {
        console.error;
        sql.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userData (userId TEXT, username TEXT, level INTEGER, money INTEGER, time INTEGER)").then(() => {
            sql.run("INSERT INTO userData (userId, username, level, money, time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [message.author.id, sender.username, 0, 0, 0]);
        });
    });
});
```

Commands that read the data and send the contents in a message work fine, such as:

```
if (msg === prefix + 'MONEY') {
        sql.get(`SELECT * FROM userData WHERE userId ="${sender.id}"`).then(row => {
            message.channel.send(`You have: $${row.money}`)
        })
    }
```

However, I am not very knowledgeable in sqlite and the documentation on sorting/displaying does not seem to work for me. I have tried just to see how many total users there are and how much money they have (for minigames):

```
if (msg === prefix + 'LEADERBOARD') {
        sql.get(`SELECT username,money FROM userData ORDER BY username`).then(rows => { 
                message.channel.send(rows); 
        })
    }
```

However, this returns: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message.` 
Any help or advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've since found an even better way to do this, by outputting an embed with the sorted number of entries in the sqlite database. This is how I got +leaderboard to display the top 3 users in the database without sending separate messages.

```
if (msg === prefix + 'LEADERBOARD') {
    sql.all('SELECT username,money FROM userdata ORDER BY money DESC LIMIT 3').then(rows => {
        var leaders = '';
        rows.forEach(function (row) {
            descr += `${row.username}: $${row.money}\n`
        })
        message.channel.send({
            embed: {
                title: "Leaderboard Top 3",
                color: 3447003,
                description: `${leaders}`
            }
        });
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const sql = require("sqlite");
sql.open("userData.sqlite");

bot.on('ready', () => {
console.log('I\'m Ready!');
});

bot.on('message', async message => {
 const data = await sql.get(/*do something*/);
 if (!data){
   // do something
  return;
 }
 // else - do something
 // for example
  return message.channel.send(`${data.username} hi!`);
});

bot.login(/*super-secret-accsess-token*/);
```

you must use async/await.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding what you mean, but when I try to await the query, node says:

`const data = await sql.get(SELECT username,money FROM data);`

`SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: await sql.get(`SELECT username, money FROM data WHERE tableName ="${message.author.id}"`);

This is not discord.js question. This is generally javascript and SQL question. And `SyntaxErrors` trigger from typo mostly.

Comment: try this:
const data = await sql.get('SELECT * FROM userData WHERE userId ="${message.author.id}"');

console.log(data);

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this does not appear to be using async at all. I simply misused sqlite and needed to change `sql.get` to `sql.all` (sql.get only reads the first row, sql.all reads all rows if you do not set a limit) and was able to console log the results easily.

The issue with `cannot send empty message` was a result of discord not being able to send the data of multiple rows in one message and had to be iterated with new lines. For this I used 'rows.forEach' and it worked fine. (Looks much better in an embed than sending multiple messages)

For anyone else that comes across this issue, this is the solution that worked for me:

```
if (msg === prefix + 'LEADERBOARD') {
    sql.all('SELECT username,money FROM userData ORDER BY money DESC').then(rows => {
        rows.forEach(function (row) {  
            console.log(row.username, row.money);
            message.channel.send(row.username + ' Has: $' + row.money);  
        }) 
    })
}
```